# UITableView scrolling slowly with UIImage

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

When I add images to a UITableView, im noticing that the first time they're added to the cell I get a jerky scroll.

I'm not loading them in remotely, instead my code looks like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

MyObject *object = [self.myObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:object.imageName];

return cell;
```

(there is no if (cell == nil) line as im registering the cell class in the view did load)

Is this a bad way of doing it? and if so, how should I add images from the main bundle to my cell's imageView?

Comment: are you using any cornerRadius for the imageview?

Comment: nope nothing quartz or anything like that . . .

Comment: how big are your images?

Comment: how big is the image? If it is a huge image that is having to be loaded, you will get these problems, as it has to be loaded in full before it can be rendered into your cells imageview. The first time jerkiness is likely caused by the image being read from disk and then cached, but read from the cache subsequently.

Comment: interesting. the images are jpgs as well . . . im reading that using a jpg instead of a png may be an issue as well . . .

Comment: definitely don't decode JPEGs/PNGs on your UI thread. Both formats require some decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try to reduce the size of images
2. If you cannot reduce the size for any reasons, try the below code (operationQueue is an ivar of the instance of NSOperationQueue)

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];
       [operationQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
           NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"name" ofType:@"jpg"];
           UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
           [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
               UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
               cell.imageView.image = image;
           }];
       }];
       return cell;
   }
   ```